# Loading web user controls from blob storage in asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net, azure-blob-storage

I am storing user control file in some other location may be in blob storage or some other place. ( not in my project work space ) and i store the url of the user control in database . Now how can load this usercontrol to my web page ?

Comment: what did you try? how are you loading those controls back to the memory? in which format?

Answer (score 0):

I'd used  following approach to load .ascx controls. In fact I've saved .ascx files into "text" field.

First of I've register a control in web.config file:

```
<pages>
  <controls>
    <add  tagPrefix="tab" src="~/pg.ascx" tagName="Test"/>
  </controls>
</pages>
```

In webform, I read .ascx content from the database and save it to pg.ascx under the root and load user control dynamically.

```
Control t = LoadControl("~/pg.ascx");
PlaceHolder1.Controls.Add(t);
```

EDIT:
I'm adding a user control definition which I've stored into StringBuilder object.

```
System.Text.StringBuilder sb = new System.Text.StringBuilder();
 sb.Append("<%@ Control Language=\"C#\" ClassName=\"m1\" %>");
 sb.Append("<script runat=\"server\">");
 sb.Append("int no=10;");
 sb.Append("public void page_load(){ for(int i=1;i<=no;i++) { Response.Write(i);} }");
 sb.Append("</script>");
 sb.Append("<h1>Hello</h1>");

 System.IO.File.WriteAllText(MapPath("~/pg.ascx"), sb.ToString());
 Control t = LoadControl("~/pg.ascx");
 PlaceHolder1.Controls.Add(t);
```

Comment: here "~/pg.ascx" is virtual path right ? , but i store my user control in some other location (blob storage) not in the website's folder

Comment: Yes it is virtual file and ASP.NET wont complaint about that file (.ascx) - whether it is exists or not.

Comment: But my .ascx file is not under root . its outside the project folder

Comment: It doesn't matter where that file is stored but the fact is you must have to copy it or create it (web user control) into current application.

Comment: Cant i bundle my user control in a dll and load from dat . I use this technique for by BO classes . Since they are inside a class library , I load them from assembly which is created using activator .createinstance . Cant i do something like that ? I couldnt do so since this is an ui file which is inside a web application . Is there any way to achieve in that manner ?