# How to load a UserControl dynamically with LoadControl Method (Type, object[])

Tags: c#, asp.net, user-controls

I am a bit new to user controls. my user control class is ucDefault . I dont have any constructors explicitly specified . I have to load my user control with the default constructor . How can i do it ?

Answer (score 2):

Try,

```
Control control=LoadControl("~/UserControlFile.ascx");
```

My answers of threads posted by you:

1. [How to load a web usercontrol from a physical path rather than a virtual path](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7551234/how-to-load-a-web-usercontrol-from-a-physical-path-rather-than-a-virtual-path)
2. [Loading web user controls from blob storage in asp.net](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7538194/loading-web-user-controls-from-blob-storage-in-asp-net)

Edit:

Here is a TestControl.cs located at App_code

```
public class TestControl : UserControl
{
    public TestControl() { }
    public TestControl(string message)
    {
        SayHello = message;
    }
    public string SayHello { get; set; }

    public override void RenderControl(HtmlTextWriter writer)
    {
        base.RenderControl(writer);
        writer.Write(SayHello);
    }
}
```

and code to loads/creates a control object:

```
TestControl tc = (TestControl)LoadControl(typeof(TestControl), new object[] { "Hello Buddy" });
```

Comment: This is using the first overload of LoadControl right? I am asking hw can i do it using the second overload .

Comment: Please take a look at this thread - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/240850/asp-net-usercontrol-loadcontrol-issue

Comment: Hi , i have added a comment in the thread Loading web user controls from blob storage in asp.net . Can you look at it once ?

Comment: i have followed what you have told  . But during loading , labels of user control get null values so it throws exception